# UNIX pipes on C block on read

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I'm struggling to implement a shell with pipelines for class.

```
typedef struct {
    char** cmd;
    int in[2];
    int out[2];
} cmdio;

cmdio cmds[MAX_PIPE + 1];
```

Commands in the pipeline are read and stored in `cmds`.

`cmdio[i].in` is the pair of file descriptors of the input pipe returned by `pipe()`. For the first command, which reads from terminal input, it is just {fileno(stdin), -1}. `cmdin[i].out`is similar for the output pipe/terminal output. `cmdio[i].in` is the same as `cmd[i-1].out`. For example:

```
$ ls -l | sort | wc

CMD: ls -l 
IN: 0 -1
OUT: 3 4

CMD: sort 
IN: 3 4
OUT: 5 6

CMD: wc 
IN: 5 6
OUT: -1 1
```

We pass each command to process_command, which does a number of things:

```
for (cmdi = 0; cmds[cmdi].cmd != NULL; cmdi++) {
    process_command(&cmds[cmdi]);
}
```

Now, inside process_command:

```
if (!(pid_fork = fork())) {
    dup2(cmd->in[0], fileno(stdin));
    dup2(cmd->out[1], fileno(stdout));    
    if (cmd->in[1] >= 0) {
        if (close(cmd->in[1])) {
            perror(NULL);
        }
    }
    if (cmd->out[0] >= 0) {
        if (close(cmd->out[0])) {
            perror(NULL);
        }
    }
    execvp(cmd->cmd[0], cmd->cmd);
    exit(-1);
}
```

The problem is that reading from the pipe blocks forever:

```
COMMAND $ ls | wc
Created pipe, in: 5 out: 6
Foreground pid: 9042, command: ls, Exited, info: 0
[blocked running read() within wc]
```

If, instead of exchanging the process with `execvp`, I just do this:

```
if (!(pid_fork = fork())) {
    dup2(cmd->in[0], fileno(stdin));
    dup2(cmd->out[1], fileno(stdout));
    if (cmd->in[1] >= 0) {
        if (close(cmd->in[1])) {
            perror(NULL);
        }
    }
    if (cmd->out[0] >= 0) {
        if (close(cmd->out[0])) {
            perror(NULL);
        }
    }

    char buf[6];
    read(fileno(stdin), buf, 5);
    buf[5] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", buf);
    exit(0);
}
```

It happens to work:

```
COMMAND $ cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | cmd4 | cmd5 
Pipe creada, in: 11 out: 12
Pipe creada, in: 13 out: 14
Pipe creada, in: 15 out: 16
Pipe creada, in: 17 out: 18
hola!
Foreground pid: 9251, command: cmd1, Exited, info: 0
Foreground pid: 9252, command: cmd2, Exited, info: 0
Foreground pid: 9253, command: cmd3, Exited, info: 0
Foreground pid: 9254, command: cmd4, Exited, info: 0
hola!
Foreground pid: 9255, command: cmd5, Exited, info: 0
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't got enough closes.  In the code:

```
if (!(pid_fork = fork())) {
    dup2(cmd->in[0], fileno(stdin));
    dup2(cmd->out[1], fileno(stdout));    
    if (cmd->in[1] >= 0) {
        if (close(cmd->in[1])) {
            perror(NULL);
        }
    }
    if (cmd->out[0] >= 0) {
        if (close(cmd->out[0])) {
            perror(NULL);
        }
    }
    execvp(cmd->cmd[0], cmd->cmd);
    exit(-1);
}
```

After you've duplicated the pipes to `stdin` and `stdout` (via `fileno()`), you need to close the pipes:

```
if (!(pid_fork = fork())) {
    dup2(cmd->in[0], fileno(stdin));
    dup2(cmd->out[1], fileno(stdout));    
    if (cmd->in[1] >= 0) {
        if (close(cmd->in[1])) {
            perror(NULL);
        }
    }
    if (cmd->out[0] >= 0) {
        if (close(cmd->out[0])) {
            perror(NULL);
        }
    }
    close(cmd->in[0]);  // Or your error checked version, but I'd use a function
    close(cmd->out[1]);     
    execvp(cmd->cmd[0], cmd->cmd);
    exit(-1);
}
```

The programs aren't finishing because there is a write end of the file still open.  Also, don't forget that if the parent process (shell) creates the pipes, it must close both ends of the pipe.  Not closing enough pipes is probably the most common mistake when starting to learn plumbing with pipes.

Comment: Hum, doesn't work :\ It's still the same, except stdin/stdout get closed before running the command so for example `cat` fails with `cat: stdin: Bad file descriptor`. But even if I avoid closing stdin/out the behavior is the same as before.

As far as I understand both `cmd->(in|out)[(0|1)]` refer to the same underlying files as `fileno(std(in|out)`, don't they?

Comment: Well, each pipe has a read descriptor and a write descriptor.  As I understand it, you have two pipes between parent and child (or between the two children).  In each child process, you will want just a `dup2()` of the read end of one pipe open on `stdin` and just the `dup2()` of the write end of the other pipe open on `stdout`; all four of the original ends of the pipe should be closed (which is what surprises people).  I'm not sure if we've got enough of the code to tell what else is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I wasn't closing both ends of the pipes from the parent like you said. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

All right, I finally solved it.

On the parent process, just after the whole child fork, I put:

```
f (cmd->in[0] != fileno(stdin)) {
    close(cmd->in[0]);
    close(cmd->in[1]);
}
```

And voilà. I had done something like that before but I mistyped and did `close(cmd->out[0]);` instead. So that's it. It makes sense now.